# fileupload function not triggered in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

hi  im working on knockout and im facing some issue . I have a Knockout form and in that i have a file upload option i want to trigger the even by clicking the upload button

http://jsfiddle.net/sornalingam/MSgdh/3/

above is my fiddle link

```
        $('input[type=file]').change(function () {

            file = this.files[0];
            name = file.name;

            alert(name);

        });
```

but in the above code it is not triggered .

can anyone help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify your html as below

```
<div>
<input type="file" data-bind="event: { change: function() { upload($element.files[0]) } }" id="fileUpload">            
</div>

<div>
<input id="btn" data-bind="click:trigger" type="submit" value="upload" />
</div>
```

And js as below

```
        var ff = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.fileUpload = ko.observable();
        self.processFiles = function () {
            var gg = self.fileUpload();
        };
        self.trigger = function(){    
            $('#fileUpload').click(); 
        };
        self.upload = function(file){
             alert(file.name);
        };
    };

ko.applyBindings(new ff());
```

**Note**: i have added 2 new functions called `trigger` and `upload`

And here is a link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MSgdh/11/)

Comment: but  im getting only by clicking  double time upload button

Comment: I can trigger the event but alert(name); and this part is not working  $('input[type=file]').change(function () {

                         file = this.files[0];
                         name = file.name;

                         alert(name);

                 });